# How can get json interface of the smart contract

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I export JSON interface from compile.js file but deploy.js file not work
it shows error as

> RuntimeError: abort(Error: You must provide the JSON interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object.). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.

here is compile.js

```
  const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, 'utf-8');

//console.log(solc.compile(source,1));


var input = JSON.stringify({
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'lottery.sol': {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {

            // Enable the metadata and bytecode outputs of every single contract.
            "*": {
                "*": ["metadata", "evm.bytecode"]
            },
            // Enable the abi and opcodes output of MyContract defined in file def.
            "def": {
                "Lottery": ["abi"]
            },
           


        }
    }
})

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(input));

const interface = output.contracts['lottery.sol'].Lottery.abi;
const bytecode = output.contracts['lottery.sol'].Lottery.evm.bytecode.object;

module.exports = {
    interface,
    bytecode,
};
```

after that export this to deploy.js file

```
 
const HDwalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const {interface,bytecode}= require('./compile.js');


const provider = new HDwalletProvider(
    '',
    'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/9ba5113757f648aaaab4d53e65898119'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async()=>{
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log(accounts);
    console.log("contract is deployed by manager with address",accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
     .deploy({data : '0x'+bytecode})
     .send({gas : '2000000' , from : accounts[0]});

     console.log('contract deployed to address ', result.options.address);
}

deploy();
```

finally, show error
JSON interface error
Please help me,I am just a beginner at web3.js.I follow old tutorial to know the workflow
But it does not match with updated versions
here is depend

```
 "dependencies": {
    "next": "^11.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "solc": "^0.8.6",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "web3": "^1.5.2"
  }
```

I need someone help to get deployed address to set here
lottery.js file

```
 import web3 from './web3.js';
const address = '';
const abi = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"enterLottery","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"manager","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"participants","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pickWinner","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in compile.js

```
var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))); // an object
// it spits out bytecode and interface


module.exports = output.contracts["Lottery.sol"]["Lottery"];
```

in deploy.js

```
    const { abi, evm } = require("./compile");
```

Answer (score 1):

compile.js

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require("solc");

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Example.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, "utf8");

const input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {
    "Example.sol": {
      content: source,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

module.exports = output.contracts["Example.sol"]["Example"];
```

here is my mocha test file example.test.js:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { abi, evm } = require("../compile");

let accounts;
let exampleContract;
beforeEach(async () => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  // Use one of those accounts to deploy the contract
  exampleContract = await new web3.eth
    .Contract(abi)
    .deploy({
      data: evm.bytecode.object,
      arguments: ["Hi there"],
    })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000 });
});

describe("Example", () => {
  it("deploys a contract", () => {
    console.log(exampleContract);
  });
});
```